# Java Multithreading - Thread2 enters syncronised method even when thread1 is inside it

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public synchronized void logic() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Thread ended");
    }
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside run method");
        logic();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
        MyThread thread2 = new MyThread();
        MyThread thread3 = new MyThread();

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
    }
}
```

Output for above code is as follows

```
inside run method
inside run method
Thread started
inside run method
Thread-1
Thread started
Thread-0
Thread started
Thread-2
<<<After few seconds>>>
Thread ended
Thread ended
Thread ended
```

As per my understanding, any/all threads can enter into run method (when thread.start()) is called.
logic method is syncronised. When one thread is in syncronized method, other threads should wait untill the thread inside syncronized method is executed completely.

In output ,
In line no 3 , I can see some thread is has entered to logic method (let say that is thread1) which is syncronised. so *Thread started* is printed. This thread has not ended.
At line no 7 , we can see *Thread started* is printed again. that means other thread (let say thread0) also entered logic method which is syncronised.

Now my question is, logic method has been executed by thread1, how can thread2 execute logic method before thread1 executes it completely

The result should be like this:

Thread2(assume) will enter logic method only if no threads are currently in logic method

Comment: `logic` is a synchronized **instance** method. That's the same as doing `synchronized (this) { /* method body */ }`. You have three different threads synchronizing on three different objects (themselves). You have to synchronize on the same object if you want mutual exclusion.

Comment: (If the method was `static synchronized`, the threads would all synchronize on the `Class` object and your code would exhibit mutual exclusion.)

Comment: (Also ... extending `Thread` is generally a bad idea.  A better idea is to provide a `Runnable` to `Thread::start`.  Better still, use an `ExecutorService` instance to manage the thread life-cycle.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is way to program your idea.

The program starts three threads on a single runnable object (which has some synchronized code).

```
public class Threads {

    private synchronized void logic() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Ending " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    
    private Runnable r = new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            logic();
        }
    };
        
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Threads().runner();
    }
    
    private void runner() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "T2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r, "T3");
        t1.start(); 
        t2.start(); 
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

What is [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Runnable.html)?

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose
> instances are intended to be executed by a thread. The class must
> define a method of no arguments called run.

---

The same result with different programming:

```
public class Threads {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    
        // Single instance of runnable object whose run method is
        // invoked by a thread object with this runnable as a target.
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        
        // Multiple threads created and started with the same runnable as target
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "T2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r, "T3");
        t1.start(); 
        t2.start(); 
        t3.start();
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        logic();
    }
    
    private synchronized void logic() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Ending " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your desired behavior is to synchronize the method on the class object.

```
public void logic() {
    synchronized (MyThread.class) {
        // Your logic
    }
}
```

Another way is to use a static object as a lock at class level.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static Object CLASS_LEVEL_LOCK = new Object();

    public void logic() {
        synchronized (CLASS_LEVEL_LOCK) {
            // Your logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note for questioner: This works because `MyThread.class` (a class literal) always returns the same `java.lang.Class` object (ignoring class loader shenanigans), meaning any thread trying to enter this critical section is synchronizing on the _same_ object.